# Translate Previously Drawn Elements (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, translate-animation

How do I transform previously drawn elements? I've drawn a rough 4 million vertices to the screen, and I'd like to translate them after they are drawn. I'd prefer not to redraw them each time I want to translate them (4 million!)

Here is the relevant code.

```
glOrtho(0, 1024, 0, 576, 0, -4096);
glTranslatef(-512, -288, 512);
glRotatef(45, 1, 0, 0);
glTranslatef(512, 0, -512);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1.F, 1.F, 1.F);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_INT, 0, &vertices[0]);
glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, vertexIndex.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &vertexIndex[0]);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
// I would like to translate here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible, your vertex positions are internally multiplied with a transformation matrix to get the final position which is drawn on the screen.

So if you try to change the matrix after drawing it doesn't have any effect on the drawn vertices, and its goo that way.

To solve your problem just transform it before drawing... its the standard way, there is no other way to do it.

Comment: Surely there must be a way. It's not really possible to redraw the 14 million vertices every frame. It takes about a second to render...

Comment: @Binero: Then maybe that's a problem you should look at. You should get better hardware or optimize your rendering or something.

Comment: or you should try to reduce your massive polygoncount

Comment: @NicolBolas & Quonix - The polygon count I have is fully optimized. The scene is just massive, and there aren't many flat bits. Without optimization there would be about 20 million vertices.

Comment: @Binero: I didn't say anything about reducing your polygon count. I said to *optimize your rendering*. This could include reducing state changes, making fewer rendering calls, using a better visibility culling algorithm, etc.

Comment: @NicolBolas The polygon count was mainly pointed at Quonix. The current polygon count is the absolute minimum. The 4 million only includes visible vertices, no vertices have duplicates. No vertices behind other polygons are sent as they aren't visible etc.

Comment: @Binero: "*No vertices behind other polygons are sent as they aren't visible etc.*" None? You have absolutely no overdraw? How did you manage that? I'm guessing the overhead of pulling that off is probably where your performance is going. The overall point is that you can't just magic pixels into other pixels. The "objects" don't exist anymore. Therefore, if you want to draw the scene from a different perspective, you need to *draw the scene* again. If that's a problem, then you need to find a way to make it not a problem.

Comment: @Binero: a first step at optimization could be to use VBOs, pushing the same 14 million vertices from client memory to the GPU every frame is just insane.

Comment: @NicolBolas There is no overhead caused by minimizing the vertices, as it can very easily tell if one is visible or not. Calculating if they are visible only takes 58 milliseconds, and can be done for all rotations at initialization. The code I showed in the OP is sucking up all performance.

Comment: @Binero well then just use a VBO and only update the data when you rotate. I think uploading the data every frame may slow you down a little. If that doesn't fix much then you could try to render to an FBO, then just shift the image by translating a quad and only rendering what newly came into view. But this only works with orthographic projection. Another possibility to speed up your rendering would be to turn the resolution down significantly while moving and then increasing the resolution again when movement has stopped.

Comment: @Binero: "*Calculating if they are visible only takes 58 milliseconds, and can be done for all rotations at initialization.*" So, using client memory instead of buffer objects, which you're doing *precisely because* of this pre-calculated visibility stuff, has zero overhead? Nonsense.

Comment: @NicolBolas I never said VBOs are bad, I just don't think that it'll help that much. (4 million!)